# Python: Change default application for specified mime type on Linux

Tags: python, linux, mime-types

I tried changing default application used to open specified file types using

```
gnomevfs.mime_set_default_application(mime_type, application_id)
```

What I received was this warning: libgnomevfs-WARNING **: Deprecated function.  User modifications to the MIME database are no longer supported.

Since I am making a file manager I really need to be able to change this as a part of file/directory properties dialog. Is there a way around it, how Nautilus does this without asking for additional priviledges?

Answer (score 2):

You probably should just invoke `xdg-mime` from the xdg-utils package. Syntax:

```
xdg-mime query default mimetype

xdg-mime default application.desktop mimetype
```

Comment: Yes, I tried doing that but in Ubuntu this doesn't do much. After calling `xdg-mime default...` Nautilus still shows that different application is set as default although `xdg-mime query` returns value I've set.

Comment: `xdg-mime query default` scans only the `defaults.list` files, making it quite weak and useless